# React 17: Should useEffect / useCallback be called before an element is mounted?

Tags: reactjs

We have recently moved from React 16 to 17. We have a few instances where we do the following pattern:

```
const Component = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ref.current.offsetWidth);
    // setTimeout(() => console.log(ref.current.offsetWidth), 50);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={ref} >Some Text</div>
  )
```

Since migrating to React 17, `ref.current.offsetWidth` will sometimes still be `0` when the `useEffect` callback is called. Some other details:

- If I add a timeout, the value returned by `ref.current.offsetWidth` will be correct most of the time,
- using `useLayoutEffect` instead makes no difference
- if I debug the code i can see that the elements are not mounted yet on the dom.

This issue is very hard to reproduce minimalistically since it only happens when you have a relatively big tree of components to render.

The same problem also exists when using [callback refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs).

I'm currently going around this by implementing my own `useCallbackRef` that internally uses `useState` and only returns a value once it was measured to have some height.

So my question is: Is there any guarantee that `useEffect` is called AFTER the DOM has been mounted? Is this something that was changed in React 17? Is this a bug I should dig deeper into?

Comment: Getting dom measurements should be done using the `useLayoutEffect` as this runs after all dom mutations have been peformed, for reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect

Comment: `useEffect` is called only _after_ the render of the component. One reason why `offsetWidth` could be zero is because it is hidden or one of its ancestor element is hidden because `display` property is set to `none` in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there is a bug with useEffect/useLayoutEffect, but rather misunderstanding when does useRef obtain the value.

```
const ref = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  if(ref.current){
    console.log(ref.current.offsetWidth);
  }
}, [ref.current]);

return (
   <div ref={ref} >Some Text</div>
)
```

Comment: putting the `ref.current` on the dependencies is irrelevant since a ref change does not trigger a rerender. The `if guard` is useful to check if the ref is defined, which it is, the `offsetWidth` is `0`,

Answer (score -1):

You should use `useLayoutEffect` instead (link [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect)).

The signature is identical to useEffect, but it fires synchronously after all DOM mutations.

Comment: sorry, but this does not fix my problem nor answers my question. The `useEffect` hook should still not be called after mounting according to the documentation:

`The function passed to useEffect will run after the render is committed to the screen. `